# Do I need to implement a refresh system for my JWT token for Django clients?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm trying to create a well-rounded authentication/registration/login system in Django using the rest framework. I've slowly started wrapping my head on how to get it done well.

I want to be satisfied with my token situation, however after reading all the docs and looking at other Git repos, I've seem to dug myself in a hole of confusion. To my understanding, there are some libraries that do token authentication/refreshing for you, others give you the tools to create one.

I'm not sure if I have a solid base to build a token refresh function given my code below. How can I implement a token refresh system for users that log-in?

Here is my code, it works fine and I see registration data in my User model.

`serializers.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=65, min_length=8, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=4)
    username = serializers.RegexField("^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{3,29}$")
    first_name = serializers.RegexField("^[A-Za-z]+((\s)?((\'|\-|\.)?([A-Za-z])+))*$", max_length=32, min_length=2)
    last_name = serializers.RegexField("^[A-Za-z]+((\s)?((\'|\-|\.)?([A-Za-z])+))*$", max_length=32, min_length=2)
    
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']
        
    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'email': ('Email is already in use')})
        return super().validate(attrs)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

`backend.py` [my authenitication system]

```
import jwt

from rest_framework import authentication, exceptions
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class JWTAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    
    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth_data = authentication.get_authorization_header(request)
        
        if not auth_data:
            return None
        
        prefix, token = auth_data.decode('utf-8').split(' ')
        
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
            
            user = User.objects.get(email=payload['email'])
            return (email, token)
            
        except jwt.DecodeError as identifier:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Your token is invalid')
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as identifier:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Your token has expired, please try again')
            
    
        return super().authenticate(request)
```

`views.py` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import auth
import jwt

# Create your views here.
class RegisterView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
class LoginView(GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        email = data.get('email','')
        password = data.get('password','')
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password) 
        
        if user:
            auth_token = jwt.encode({'email':user.email}, settings.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
            
            serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
            
            data = {
                "email": serializer.data,
                "token": auth_token,        
            }
            
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            
        return Response({"detail": "Invalid credentials"}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Should I re-do my authentication system to include a token refresh system?

Comment: As it is, you can't invalidate tokens in any way.